# Massless scalar $\phi^3$ tree-level scattering amplitudes?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering

The [CHY formula](http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.2199) for massless scattering at tree-level can compute i.e. scalar, gluon and graviton amplitudes. For gluon scattering there are many other resources available to compute all kinds of tree-level amplitudes, like for instance the [GGT package](http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.3991), so that it is easy to compare results for lower point examples. I wonder if there exist any resources on scalar scattering amplitudes that give amplitude results independently from CHY, in order to compare examples? I was not able to find any reference on that. Thanks for any suggestion!